# Android customize shell UI

Tags: android, shell, user-interface

Does anyone know how to develop the customization shell UI like this [one](http://www.tsfui.com/shell/index.html)?

Does it need to make from Android ROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad, but you can start at the [Android Home Sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html).